# Difference between imperfect indicative and imperfect progressive

Tags: verbos, tiempos-verbales, pretérito-imperfecto

> Yo **estaba durmiendo** cuando me llamaste.
>
> Yo **dormía** cuando me llamaste.

Both have the same meaning of "*I was sleeping when you called me*". I can't really understand if there's any difference between imperfect indicative and imperfect progressive.

Comment: I can't really tell a difference either.

Comment: I suppose you could say that `estaba durmiendo` translates to something like `was in the process of sleeping`

Comment: @dockeryZ Not sure... In English there's only one "past progressive" tense which I've always thought that imperfect is the equivalent.

Comment: They are both indicative, btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this sentence, and many of the kind, there is no difference between the imperfect and the progressive. I would personally use the progressive, but the form with the imperfect is grammatically correct and its meaning is clear.

The imperfect can also express a habitual action in the past (which in English would employ *used to* or the modal *would*), and in that usage you cannot substitute the progressive:

> *Yo jugaba mucho al fútbol cuando era pequeño.*
>   "I used to play football a lot when I was little."

A habitual action in the past can employ a progressive form, but only in a construction using an adverb or phrase like *siempre* or *todo el tiempo* (this is mostly as in English):

> *Yo estaba siempre jugando al fútbol cuando era pequeño.*
>   "I was always playing football when I was little."

This emphasizes the repetition or regularity of the action.

Some times the verb does not lend itself to use in the progressive, even in constructions exactly parallel to that of your example:

> *Tenía las manos ocupadas cuando tocaste a la puerta.*
>   "I had my hands full when you knocked on the door."

(i.e. you cannot use **estaba teniendo las manos ocupadas*).

In general I would advise that, for a structure like your example ("to be doing something (continuous) when something else (suddenly) happened"), you should use the progressive. The sentence will then have a main clause in the progressive tense and a temporal subordinate in the indefinite preterite.

Comment: The answer made me start to think that "*estaba descubriendo*" is gramatically correct, even if *descubrir* is preterit by nature...

Comment: Ah, but you can discover something gradually, and the phrase comes rather naturally in some cases.

Comment: Why cannot *estaba teniendo* be used? Can it never be used, or only in this context? SpanishDict did include *estaba teniendo* in its conjugation table for *tener*, with an example: *Para decirle la verdad, yo estaba teniendo una barbacoa.* I'm not sure if SpanishDict controlls for grammaticality in its examples, or if they're even real examples; maybe they're automatically generated?

Comment: To me, *estaba teniendo una barbacoa* sounds like a literal translation from English and is ungrammatical. In general *tener* shows a continuous state by itself and therefore doesn't go well with the progressive. You only see *estaba teniendo* in sentences where *tener* is a synonym for *sostener* "to hold, to support", that is, when it's about the physical action of applying force to keep something in place or in your hands.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a paradigm I find helpful:

> **Estaba caminando** a la casa cuando **vino el aguacero**. | I was walking home when the downpour started.

First, we set the scene; then comes something sudden, like a thunderclap.

Now consider this sentence:

> Yo me preguntaba si me iban a invitar. | I was wondering if they were going to invite me.

Here I prefer "preguntaba" because "estaba preguntando" isn't really necessary, given that there's no sudden action.  You *could* use the progressive here, but you don't need to, and the imperfect indicative is more elegant.

The presence of an adverb will often nudge one toward the imperfect indicative, for example:

> Apenas empezaba a llover cuando llegamos. | It was just starting to rain when we arrived.

Without the adverb you could go either way (empezaba OR estaba empezando).

---

Note that in Mexico (at least), there is another way to construct the progressive: replace "estaba" with "iba" or "venía."  Examples:

1. Suppose my son is telling me a story, and the order of the incidents has gotten a bit confused.  I might ask

   > Espera, no entendí.  ¿Venías caminando a la casa cuando pasó eso? | Were you walking home when that happened?
2. My partner asks me if I'm almost ready to leave the house.  I respond

   > Iba buscando una carta que me llegó ayer pero mejor busco más tarde.  Vámonos.
3. > Iba caminando a la casa cuando vino el aguacero.

These three sentences feel *very* progressive.